# Capistrano's `cap production deploy:migrate` won't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano

**I'm having trouble getting Capistrano to run my database migrations.**

I'm using a VPS offered by DigitalOcean to host my Rails application.  Previously I would use `git push heroku master` to host my side projects on Heroku but now I want something a little cheaper.  I'm trying to use [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) to deploy my code to the server (using [this](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04) tutorial to get up and running).  I can successfully get my new commits onto the server, however, I can't get Capistrano to run my database migrations.

To showcase my problem I created a new model, committed the changes, pushed to the Github repo, and then ran `cap production deploy`.  I looked on the server and I can see the new migration file.  [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/04be43c395d3c54b3660) is the output from that command in case it's helpful in debugging the problem.

When I run `cap production deploy:migrate` nothing happens to the database:

```
~/Projects/rails/testapp $ cap production deploy:migrate
DEBUG[aec67347] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3 ] on 104.236.181.65
DEBUG[aec67347] Command: [ -d ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3 ]
DEBUG[aec67347] Finished in 1.107 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

And here's my PostgeSQL database on the production server (nothing changed):

```
testapp_production=> \d
               List of relations
 Schema |       Name        |   Type   | Owner  
--------+-------------------+----------+--------
 public | cars              | table    | deploy
 public | cars_id_seq       | sequence | deploy
 public | schema_migrations | table    | deploy
 public | users             | table    | deploy
 public | users_id_seq      | sequence | deploy
(5 rows)
```

Now, when I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate` on the server it successfully runs the migration, evidenced by the new `manufacturers` table:

```
testapp_production=> \d
                 List of relations
 Schema |         Name         |   Type   | Owner  
--------+----------------------+----------+--------
 public | cars                 | table    | deploy
 public | cars_id_seq          | sequence | deploy
 public | manufacturers        | table    | deploy
 public | manufacturers_id_seq | sequence | deploy
 public | schema_migrations    | table    | deploy
 public | users                | table    | deploy
 public | users_id_seq         | sequence | deploy
(7 rows)
```

**How come `cap production deploy:migrate` won't run the database migration?**  Also, I was under the impression that `cap production deploy` would automatically run any new migrations, is this true?

My app's configurations can be found here: https://github.com/Abundnce10/testapp

Here is my `Capfile`:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rbenv'

set :rbenv_type, :user # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.3'
```

Here's my `/config/deploy.rb` file:

```
lock '3.1.0'
set :application, 'testapp'
set :repo_url, 'https://github.com/Abundnce10/testapp'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/testapp'
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :deploy do

  before :publishing, 'deploy:migrate'

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

  after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

Here's my `/config/deploy/production.rb` file:

```
set :stage, :production
server '104.236.181.65', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Either your migrations are not pushed into repository and hence not available within `releases/timestamp/db/migrate` directory or `schema_migrations` table has incorrect migration timestamp. To check that `select * from schema_migrations` on production and see what migration timestamp it matches.

Comment: The migrations _are_ in the repository (see [https://github.com/Abundnce10/testapp/tree/master/db/migrate](https://github.com/Abundnce10/testapp/tree/master/db/migrate)) and I see all 4 of them on the server (~/testapp/releases/20141130081711/db/migrate).  The `schema migrations` table contains the first 3 migrations (with correct timestamps) but misses the newest migrations -- due to the fact that `cap production deploy:migrate` won't run the new migration.  I can manually run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate` but I'd like to rely on Capistrano so that I can rollback.

Comment: It looks like I didn't include `db` in my `/config/deploy/production.rb` file - `server 'XXX.XXX.XXX.xx', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}`.  Adding `db` allowed the db migrations to run automatically when I deploy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't include `db` in my `/config/deploy/production.rb` file.  It now looks like:

```
set :stage, :production
server '104.236.181.65', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
```

Adding `db` to `:roles` allowed the database migrations to run automatically when I run `cap production deploy`.